# Double ng-repeat call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am newbie in AngularJS. Maybe my question will be stupid.Sorry in advance.

I have index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular/angular-csp.css">

    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
<div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'controllers'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
                renderOnFirstLoad: false
            });

    }]);
```

controllers.js:

```
'use strict';
var controllers = angular.module('controllers',[]);

controllers.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.friends = {'name': 'name1', 'picture': {'data': {'url': 'url1'}}};
}
])
```

and templates/home.html

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="HomeCtrl" ng-cloak>
    <ul class="friends">
        <li ng-repeat="friend in friends" class="thumbnail">
            <div>
            <img src="{{friend.picture.data.url}}"/>
            </div>
            <p>{{friend.name}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I open app there are two **li** items, but I use only one value in friends variable. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `$scope.friends` as array:

```
  'use strict';
    var controllers = angular.module('controllers',[]);

    controllers.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.friends = [{'name': 'name1', 'picture': {'data': {'url': 'url1'}}}];
    }
    ])
```

html code:

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="HomeCtrl" ng-cloak>
    <ul class="friends">
        <li ng-repeat="friend in friends" class="thumbnail">
            <div>
            <img src="{{friend.picture.data.url}}"/>
            </div>
            <p>{{friend.name}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```